# Why this below exec command is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why these below statements are giving error

```
>>> exec("x={}".format('b'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

I need the result to be

```
x='b'
```

Comment: Why don't you simply do `"x={}".format('b')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide another pair of quotes

```
>>> exec("x={}".format("'b'"))
>>> x
'b'
```

**Why?**

When you write

```
exec("x={}".format('b'))
```

you are trying to write

```
x=b
```

obviously python doesn't know what `b` is unless you have defined it before.

Where as when you write

```
exec("x={}".format("'b'"))
```

It is same as

```
x='b'
```

Comment: @RajeshKumar Sorry but I didnt get you in this statement *How to use "for" loop for the above two statements?*

Comment: I am trying to use something like this

" for (x, y) in data.items():
              exec("{}={}".format(x, y)) "

y can be either char or int or datetime object, please let me know will it work or not